# 1120 Error Adobe Animate, button action script doesnt work.

Tags: animate-cc

I'm doing an assignment for class and I keep getting this 1120 error on nearly every kind of button I try to create. I have reached out to the teacher for help but have not gotten any assistance back yet.

The exact error i am getting is. 1120:Access of undefined property next_button.

```js
stop();


/* Click to Go to Next Frame and Stop
Clicking on the specified symbol instance moves the playhead to the next frame and stops the movie.
*/

next_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_4);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 nextFrame();
}
```

this is my code, I have the instance name matching on the button. I have a similar code in my first scene of my animation and it works just fine, so I'm unsure what I am doing wrong.